# excluding column already defined numeric in list

Tags: r

I have a list of column types where we defined the type of column for example character type or numeric. and  now i am checking the frequency of numeric values in all columns.

so here i want to apply the code below for column excluding which are already defined as integer or which are defined as character

```
col_list <- list(newid = as.character(),
col1 = as.integer(),
col2 = as.integer()
col3 = as.character()
col_max = as.character())

data <- data.frame(newid= c(212,132,354,222,263,235,233,263,106,135,144),
                   col1= c(1,2,2,1,4,3,2,4,0,5,0),
                   col2= c(1,1,0,3,2,4,1,0,1,3,5),
                   col3= c(1,1,0,3,2,4,1,0,1,3,5),
                   col4= c(1,1,0,3,2,4,1,0,1,3,5),
                   col_max= c("NM","mn","PA","OH","KL","AB","OT","HA","AM","LA","GA"))

data %>% summarise(across(starts_with("col") &  !ends_with("_max"), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
df1 <- df %>% summarise(across(starts_with("col_") &  names(df) != ends_with("_max"), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

so here it should give statistics for col2:col4 only dynamically
so after df1 i want to filter those columns which are already mentioned as.integer

Answer (score 0):

"so here i want to apply the code below for column excluding which are already defined as integer or which are defined as character"

If you want to exclude columns defined as integer or as character, you will have empty data frame. I assume you do not want to do that and want to select only integer columns. This should do it.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%select(where(is.integer))
```

And then summarise it in any way you need, as it is not really clear from the question.

Comment: And the answer is still the same. data %>%select(where(is.integer))%>%summary    Your character column needs to be converted to a factor if you want any meaningful info from summary. So data$col_max<-as.factor(data$col_max)   and just change (is.integer) into (is.factor)